# Get values in NotMapped property in model class Entity Framwork Code First using linq

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have the below scenario.  I am using EF 5 Code first, MVC 4 on VS 2010.  I am using the Unit of Work and Repository pattern for my project.

I am not sure if this is possible or not.  Kindly suggest.

I have a model class representing a database table.  In the model class, I have a property that is decorated as [NotMapped].  I have a Stored Proc that returns data, similar to the model class.  However, when I get the data in a List from the SP, it does not contain value for the [NotMapped] column (SP returns data for the [NotMapped] column though).  This may be logically correct with respect to EF.

All I want to know is, do we have a way to get data populated for the [NotMapped] column.  I want to achieve, CRUD using LINQ (excluding R - Read).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend to create a separate complex type for the stored procedure results. Otherwise sooner or later you will find yourself writing code to distinguish between entities coming from the DbSet or from the stored procedure. When the come from the stored procedure they can't be used in joins, for example. Or checks whether or not the unmapped property is set.

A very dirty approach could be to have two different contexts. With code first it is possible to have different contexts with different mappings to the same types, with and without the column ignored (if you use fluent mapping, not with data annotations). But that only succeeds if you tell EF not to check the database schema, so using migrations is ruled out as well. I would not do it!! For the same reason as I mentioned above. I would hate to have a type with a property that sometimes is and sometimes isn't set.

Comment: Thanks for your comments.  How about this approach? (I think you have also hinted about the same).

1. Inherit the model class in a new class.
2. The new class will be used for the SP calls
3. Old one will be used for other Create, Update Delete operations

Comment: You could do that, if you override the unmapped property in the inherited class you could even use the same property name.