# EF 5 Code First model with [NotMapped] is not set via SqlQuery()?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get values in NotMapped property in model class Entity Framwork Code First using linq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13857999/get-values-in-notmapped-property-in-model-class-entity-framwork-code-first-using)

I am using `Entity Framework 5`'s `Code First` in my project and my model looks more or less like this:

```
public class Category
{
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual Category Parent { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public int Level { get; set; }
}
```

The generated `table` contains all columns except the Level `column` (as expected)

Now, I have a `stored procedure` which calculates the Level of the Category node in relation to it's parent.

If I execute the `stored procedure` in SQL Server Mgmt Studio it returns the columns as specified in my model **including** the [NotMapped] Level `column`.

The thing is: the Level `column` is not filled if I call the `stored procedure` like this: `Context.Database.SqlQuery<TModel>(storedProcedure, parameterArray);` where `TModel` is `Category`.

Is there any way to 're-use' this Category `model`?

Comment: Wow... I did not find that question and I always search on forehand! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You clearly say that the property "Level" is not part of your model, therefor it of course won't be filled by your stored procedure. Why would you expect any else?

The only way would be to parse the result of your sp by hand and create instances of your model class yourself.

Comment: I understand your reaction. The only thing I don't get is that the Stored Procedure's columns are not set to the columns that are available. But, your reaction made me think through my problem, I am going to try an extension `class` or so where this one extends my Category `model`

Comment: The stored procedure columns are set to the columns that are available. But your "level" column is not available in your model. Entity Framework ignores it, because you explicitly told it to do so.

Comment: I mark it as answer because it made me realize that I had to do it differently. Now I have a Model that fits the `Stored procedure` result.