# EF SqlQuery tries to map object property, even though it's attributed [NotMapped]

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a stored procedure that I execute with `context.Database.SqlQuery<MyObject>("MyProc")`

`MyObject` has a readonly property:

```
[NotMapped]
public bool IsSomething { get { return this.otherproperty == "something"; } }
```

So I get the error:

> System.IndexOutOfRangeException: IsSomething
>   at System.Data.ProviderBase.FieldNameLookup.GetOrdinal etc

Which is because MyProc doesn't have `IsSomething` in the result columns (I'm 100% sure that's probably the reason).

Shouldn't it just ignore it since it's `[NotMapped]`? Do I need to set something else for `SqlQuery`?

To make things even more weird, I only see it on production, from the logs of Stackify, and the page seems to load properly without any errors in the browser.

Comment: If it wasn't for the bounty I would vote to close this question for lacking an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @GertArnold Of course there is no MCVE, because the issue is not reproducible. Usually the people [ask for the opposite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13857999/get-values-in-notmapped-property-in-model-class-entity-framwork-code-first-using) - how to populate `NotMapped` property from LINQ/SqlQuery and the answer is of course "you can't because they are excluded from the result". Except they are using some specific buggy EF version, I'm considering the accepted trivial answer being incorrect and voting to close by the same reason as you.

Comment: @IvanStoev Maybe I should have pointed out specifically that it may be important what the rest of the capturing type looks like. Also the data returned from the sproc may have unexpected consequences. Anyway, with such vague exceptions it's always important to supply details of all moving parts. But since the bounty owner was a different person than the asker I didn't expect much of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.database.sqlquery(v=vs.113).aspx#M:System.Data.Entity.Database.SqlQuery%60%601%28System.String,System.Object%5B%5D%29)

> ## `Database.SqlQuery<TElement> Method (String, Object[])`
>
> Creates a raw SQL query that will return elements of the given generic type. **The type can be any type that has properties that match the names of the columns returned from the query**, or can be a simple primitive type. The type does not have to be an entity type. The results of this query are never tracked by the context even if the type of object returned is an entity type.....

*emphasis mine*

It is looking in the reader returned from query for the `IsSomething` as indicated by `System.Data.ProviderBase.FieldNameLookup.GetOrdinal` in the error message.

Because that column does not exist you will get the `IndexOutOfRangeException`.

> Shouldn't it just ignore it since it's `[NotMapped]` ?

No. It ignores any attributes present on the object, including `[NotMapped]`. Refer to quote referenced above

> Do I need to set something else for SqlQuery ?

I would suggest creating another object with only properties that match/map to the expected result of the procedure and using that as the generic argument of the `SqlQuery` call.

Comment: I added a column in the SP matching one of the property names that gave the error, and I stopped getting the error for that property (the others still give it).
So your suggestion is correct, the problem is because it fails to match the properties to SP result columns, even though they are marked as [NotMapped]

Answer (score 3):

> To make things even more weird, I only see it on production, from the logs of Stackify, and the page seems to load properly without any errors

I'm not familiar with Stackify logs, but based on my knowledge of EF6 I would speculate and say this is false positive log.

The documentation is not quite clear in that regard. First, entity and non entity `SqlQuery` result types are processed by different code branches. While it's true that both translations use CLR property names as column names (i.e. column name mappings for entity types are not taken into account), the ignored (`NotMapped`) properties of the entity types are indeed *excluded* from the result as expected.

Also the `IndexOutOfRangeException` in question is caught by EF code and translated to a different exception (`EntityCommandExecutionException`), which can be seen from the [source code](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework6/blob/master/src/EntityFramework/Core/Query/InternalTrees/columnmapfactory.cs) of the relevant methods [`GetMemberOrdinalFromReader`](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework6/blob/master/src/EntityFramework/Core/Query/InternalTrees/columnmapfactory.cs#L329):

```
// <summary>
// Given a store datareader and a member of an edmType, find the column ordinal
// in the datareader with the name of the member.
// </summary>
private static int GetMemberOrdinalFromReader(
    DbDataReader storeDataReader, EdmMember member, EdmType currentType,
    Dictionary<string, FunctionImportReturnTypeStructuralTypeColumnRenameMapping> renameList)
{
    int result;
    var memberName = GetRenameForMember(member, currentType, renameList);

    if (!TryGetColumnOrdinalFromReader(storeDataReader, memberName, out result))
    {
        throw new EntityCommandExecutionException(
            Strings.ADP_InvalidDataReaderMissingColumnForType(
                currentType.FullName, member.Name));
    }
    return result;
}
```

and [`TryGetColumnOrdinalFromReader`](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework6/blob/master/src/EntityFramework/Core/Query/InternalTrees/columnmapfactory.cs#L380):

```
// <summary>
// Given a store datareader and a column name, try to find the column ordinal
// in the datareader with the name of the column.
// </summary>
// <returns> true if found, false otherwise. </returns>
private static bool TryGetColumnOrdinalFromReader(DbDataReader storeDataReader, string columnName, out int ordinal)
{
    if (0 == storeDataReader.FieldCount)
    {
        // If there are no fields, there can't be a match (this check avoids
        // an InvalidOperationException on the call to GetOrdinal)
        ordinal = default(int);
        return false;
    }

    // Wrap ordinal lookup for the member so that we can throw a nice exception.
    try
    {
        ordinal = storeDataReader.GetOrdinal(columnName);
        return true;
    }
    catch (IndexOutOfRangeException)
    {
        // No column matching the column name found
        ordinal = default(int);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Based on the above and the lack of repro with real exception, I would say you can safely ignore that log.